# how can add a label to every row in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, tableview

I want add label to every row in tableview at right side of the row in iphone programmatically.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: you mean you want the labels added during creation of the initial view of the table, or after the table has been built and is displayed you want to then add labels to right of each cell in response to user event?

Comment: You can create label in cellForRowAtIndexPath.Whats the problem your are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 3, 100, 15)]; // For right alignment
    lblText.text = [self.arrText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell addSubview:lblText];
    [lblText release];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
    lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    lbl.text = [self.arrRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for code.
 try

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UILabel *yourLabel = nil;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect……];
    [yourLabel setTag:9999];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:addressLabel];

} 

if (!yourLabel)
    yourLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:9999];

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method :-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        //set reuseIdentifier:nil for avoid label overlapping
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    //make your label as according to you
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // add label content view of cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    return cell;
}
```